# Running a controller function from an ExtJS 6.6 href link

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

Is it possible to call a controller function from a href tag inside a html string? ... I can't seem to get anything working so i think i may be doing something wrong.

Im using ExtJS 6.6

I have some user information and then a logout link, but nothing works, this is what i have.

```
items: [{
    region: 'north',
    height: 200,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: 'column',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            columnWidth: 0.3
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            columnWidth: 0.7,
            html: '<div class="userstuff" style="text-align: right;">Hello, welcome to my page<br /><a href="#" class="logout">Log out</a></p></div>'
        }]
    }]
}]
```

The bit that i cant get going is;

```
<a href="#" class="logout">Log out</a>
```

If i use a button xtype, i can call it through the handler, and it works perfect, but i now need to change it to a text link.

This is the button code that works;

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Logout',
    handler: 'onLogout'
}
```

Any help getting this text link to call `onLogout` would be fantastic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `onLogout` using `Event delegation`.You need to attach listener on your `panel` like this

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    listeners: {
        element: 'el',
        delegate: 'a.logout',
        click: 'onLogoutClick'
    }
}
```

You can check here with working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2n0i).

**Code Snippet**

```
Ext.define('MyViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.myview',

    /**
     * This event will fire on Logout click
     */
    onLogoutClick: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'You have clicked on logout button');
    }
});

Ext.create({
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Running a controller function from an ExtJS 6.6 href link',
    layout: 'border',
    controller: 'myview',
    height: 200,
    items: [{
        region: 'north',
        height: 200,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'column',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                columnWidth: 0.3
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                columnWidth: 0.7,
                listeners: {
                    element: 'el',
                    delegate: 'a.logout',
                    click: 'onLogoutClick'
                },
                html: '<div class="userstuff" style="text-align: right;">Hello, welcome to my page<br /><a href="#" class="logout">Log out</a></p></div>'
            }]
        }]
    }],

    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Beautiful ... That is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much